# How to restore document from records center (not inplace!) in SharePoint 2013 server?

Tags: sharepoint-server, records-management, records-center

How to restore document from records center (not inplace!) in SharePoint 13 server?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in which event you trying to perform a recovery.There are couple of ways you can do this.

- If a document is updated with the latest version, you can go back and restore the previous version
- if document is deleted then check the RecycleBin for recovery.
- if document is completely gone from site then you need the backup of the content database or site collection backup. You have to restore that in different farm and then copy the required data.